# Term for relationship of set overlap without containment?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

What is the term for the *relationship* between two sets that share at least one common element, but neither set is a proper or improper subset of the other?

$$
A?B=_{def}\exists x \exists y \exists z ((x \in A) \wedge (x \notin B) \wedge (y \notin A) \wedge (y \in B) \wedge (z \in A) \wedge (z \in B))
$$

Comment: "Two sets neither of which is a subset of the other" is not good enough?

Comment: Nonempty intersection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Two non-empty non-overlapping sets fulfill that.

Comment: @user4894 A set and it's subset fulfill that.  As do identical sets.

Answer (score 0):

One idea to name the relation of two sets is to borrow concepts from logic gates. In your case we have:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\lor  & a\notin A & a\in A \\
\hline
b\notin B & 0 & 1 \\
b\in B & 1 & 1
\end{array}
$$

where a 1 indicates the intersection is non-empty and 0 implies the intersection is empty, so we could say $A \lor B$.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I'm looking for terminology, not definition.  Also, I think my question leaves the absolute complement of (A union B) undefined, rather than necessarily empty.  I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: in which case you are looking at $X$, the whole universe